# Given the table, calculate the table of joint probability of $A$ and $B$.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

> Given the below table, the sample consisted $20\%$ of $B_1$,  $20\%$ of $B_2$ and $60\%$ of $B_3$.  Calculate the table of joint probability of $A$ and $B$.
>
> $$\begin{array}{|l|l|l|l|}
>    \hline \mathsf P(A\mid B) & A_1 \qquad & A_2\qquad & A_3\qquad
> \\ \hline B_1 & 0.3 & 0.6 & 0.1
> \\ \hline B_2 & 0.6 & 0.3 & 0.1
> \\ \hline B_3 & 0.3 & 0.1 & 0.6
> \\ \hline 
> \end{array}$$

Any reasoning is appreciated!

Comment: Use $P_{AB}(a,b)=P_{A|B}(A|B) \times P(B)$

Comment: @WinVineeth That's a good answer.  You should post is as such.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Who answers doesn't matter as long as OP gets it. Now that it is answered, It's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Win Vineeth stated, you are given $\mathsf P_B(b)$ for $b\in\{B_1, B_2, B_3\}$, and the tables is for $\mathsf P_{A\mid B}(a\mid b)$.   Simply multiply as appropriate using: $$\mathsf P_{A,B}(a, b) = \mathsf P_{A\mid B}(a\mid b)~\mathsf P_B(b)$$

.

---

- PS: This is a community wiki answer to close this question.   If Win Vineeth posts his comment as an answer, please accept that instead.

Comment: Thank you for your solution @Graham Kemp ,  Actually,  P(A|B) is not clearly demonstrated. How could you know that the values in the table are the probability of A given B?  That is what i am confused.

Comment: Intuitively, I will regard the values in the table as joint probability, The original exercise doesn't tell you that the values are P(A|B). Could you give some reasoning about why do you konw that the values in the table are conditional probability?

Comment: @statistics_learning The sum of each row in the unlabeled table is $1$, and the question was asking you to find the joint probability distribution using that table and the marginal probability distribution of $B$.  The table was clearly *intended* to be the conditional probabilities of $A$ given $B$.

Comment: Thank you for explanation.I know the Bayes Rule well, But I am still can not understand why the sum of each row in the table is 1 that leads to the values are conditional probability. Could you explain more?

Comment: @statistics_learning It doesn't lead to it; but it is a *clue* that that was what the table's title was *intended* to be.  Because  $\mathsf P(A_1\mid B_1)+\mathsf P(A_2\mid B_1)+\mathsf P(A_3\mid B_1)=1$ etc, so if that was what was intended, it works.  That, and a table of conditional probabilities is the information needed to answer the question.